# svn subversion server list only repository (Takes To much time)

Tags: linux, svn, grep, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I have a problem with TIME when Im using  `svnlook tree /var/www/svn/TEST --full-paths| grep -E  'RV/13\.9\.4\.[0-9]+/$'`

**/var/www/svn/TEST ->** is quite big project has many folder and files.

**Explication**: 
I listed only the repository that named like that `RV/13.9.4.n/`
to get this result

- RV/13.9.4.0/
- RV/13.9.4.1/
- RV/13.9.4.2/

**PROBLEM** 
my command takes too long to be executed because it needs to fetch project tree

how can I avoid that to make it faster?

PS: something like `svn list [repo_path] | grep '13\.9\.4\.[0-9]+'`

Unfortunately, I can't use the command `svn list` in svn subversion machine server side (Hooks)

Comment: BTW, what hook do you write now? How do you plan to use `svnlook tree` or `svn list` and `grep` in this hook? Please, update your question with this information. I guess that I could give you further advice.

Comment: in the pre-commit hook,  I want to list some subfolders from a folder called ILS

Comment: note that you have to make sure that your pre-commit hook does not negatively affect commit times. If the hook gets stuck, commit user's commit operation will become stuck, too. You should avoid such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to run this command in your hooks, but I am not sure whether this will be faster than `svnlook tree`:

```
svn list file:///var/www/svn/ILS | grep '13\.9\.4\.[0-9]+'
```

Note the `file://` protocol.

Comment: that's what I'm looking for!! Thanks